# Шифр Цезаря на SQL (желательно оракловом)

Tags: sql, oracle

Помогите пожалуйста реализовать процедуру с кольцевым сдвигом букв и цифр в текстовой строке по принципу n+1: например, ABCD01234AB -> BCDE1234BC. Все строки в текстовом поле разной длины, разного регистра, могут встречаться знаки препинания (точки, тире, пробелы). Значения в поле могут быть также нулевыми.

На всякий случай, дополнительный вопрос - как эту процедуру применять внутри UPDATE SET?

Нужно чтобы было что-то типа такого:

```
Create procedure text_change(n varchar(1000))
declare @i char
declare @l varchar(100 char)
begin
For each @l in n
For each @i in @l
loop
@i = ????
end loop;
return @l;
end;

UPDATE название_таблицы
SET название_поля = text_change(поле)
```

Comment: А как вы получили  BCDE1234BC, они же разной длины с исходной строкой? Поле n , это строка или массив строк?

Comment: Прошу прощения, случайно ошибся. Это просто строка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В оракле для этого есть функция `translate`.

```
UPDATE название_таблицы
SET название_поля = translate(название_поля, 
                             'ABCDEF...<остальной алфавит>',
                             'BCDEFG...<остальной алфавит со смещением 1>');
```

Если надо иметь возможность задавать смещение вручную (каждый раз разное, например):

```
UPDATE название_таблицы
SET название_поля = translate(название_поля, 
                             'ABCDEF...<остальной алфавит>',
                              substr('ABCDEF...<остальной алфавит>', 14) || 
                              substr('ABCDEF...<остальной алфавит>', 1, 13));
```

Здесь у вас будет смещение 13 (смещение должно быть меньше длины алфавита).

Answer (score 0):

Например для N+13, т.н. ROT13

Посгри:

```
create or replace function pg_temp.rot13( string text )
    returns text as $rot13$
begin
    return translate( string, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklm' );
end $rot13$ language plpgsql;
```

sqlite:

```
.load rot13
SELECT rot13('grfg fgevat');
```